# NSNumber has unsignedIntValue and unsignedLongValue. I thought they were the same?

Tags: objective-c, types, nsnumber

I thought `unsigned int` meant `unsigned long int` (32 bit) by default.  Likewise, I thought `unsigned long` meant `unsigned long int` by default (32 bit).  Why the two selectors on NSNumber (`unsignedIntValue` and `unsignedLongValue`), or should I be worried about the data type bit lengths?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On LP64 (Mac OS 64 Bit) a long is 64 bit wide while an int has only 32 bit.

Comment: So an `unsigned long int` is 64 bit on Mac OS 64 bit?  Thats really odd.

Comment: What's odd about a long having 64 bit?

Comment: I expected `unsigned long long int` to be 64 bit... and I didn't think there was anything odd about that.

Comment: A `long long` is both in 32 and 64 bit architectures 64 bit wide.

Comment: So you're saying that `unsigned long long int` and `unsigned long int` are 64 bits on LP64?

Comment: @Justin, I think that definitely clarifies things.  I'm still thinking about datatypes in Windows land, apparently.

Comment: @Brett yup, just another area where C widths are implementation defined. the (paraphrased) rationale given when 64 bit was announced for OS X was that LP64 was chosen because it was the model which matched the most closely related programs (i.e. UNIX). that was the right choice, imo -- but different models can certainly be a source of confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I understand OSX and iOS have limited architectures, but in general, you should not make any assumptions about integer sizes, other than the basic relative ordering guaranteed in the standard.

If you really need a specific sized integral value, use the uint8_t, uint16_t, uint32_t, and uint64_t types.